# How to begin programming standalone applications for OS X

Tags: macos

Are there any good resources for beginning writing applications for OS X?

I'm familiar with c++, Java, php so don't necessarily need introduction to programming concepts but don't really know where to start with creating applications for a mac.

I have used Borland for creating .exe files on a PC. Is there a similar system for macs?

Comment: To state the obvious ... `XCode` (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Comment: Resources... computers/macs or developers? Xcode...Obj-C.  [Resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575037/what-are-resources-for-learning-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue in a language you already know, you can use [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/), which uses C++ and supports many platforms, including OSX.

However, the most common programming language for OSX is Objective-C, which you'll be able to find many [tutorials on-line](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=OSX%20programming%20tutorial&oq=OSX%20programming%20tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.9893j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8).

The most common IDE to use is [XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xcode/id497799835), which is free in the App Store.

Comment: Great thanks. I'd googled variations on 'create standalone application  for osx' and just got lots of python resources.